# Concurrent-safe way to insert/update in a table with linked rows

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, concurrency

I'm building an history table for my app to save objects data when some user actions are performed and if needed use the saved data to rollback changes or redo them.
My table looks like this (`user_id` and `object_id` are fks):

```sql
+-----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|     Column      |  Type   |                 Modifiers                    |
+-----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id              | integer | not null nextval('history_id_seq'::regclass) |
| user_id         | integer | not null                                     |
| object_id       | integer | not null                                     |
| object_data     | bytea   | not null                                     |
| is_active       | boolean | not null                                     |
| prev_history_id | integer |                                              |
| next_history_id | integer |                                              |
+-----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
Index :
  "history_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
  "unique_active_history_user_object" UNIQUE, btree (user_id, object_id, is_active) WHERE is_active IS TRUE
```

I keep the history elements in ordered with `prev_history_id`, `next_history_id` and it allows for easy access.

Now here's my problem. I'm struggling to find a way to perform insert/update operations in way that would not cause concurrency issues.
Inserting a new record to the history will look like this:

1. check if there's an already active history record a given `user_id`, `object_id`
2. if it's the case, set `is_active` to `false` on this record so my unique constraint won't interfer
3. insert the new record
4. if there was a record in step 1., update its `next_history_id` to point to the newly created record

So either I didn't see a simpler way to perform this or it is the design I came up isn't very efficient.

Comment: That should work just fine, as long as you do it all in a single transaction.